# Get rid of all null values in Combobox after iport data from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, notnull

I'm developing some winforms application for my office. in my application I have more than 50 comboboxes that I want to connect the MySQL  database and retrieve data. every combobox should retrieve data from certain MySQL database column. any way I successfully made a connection and retrieve data to comboboxes using below code.

but now I  have very strange problem. in my MySQL database there are lot of null values (some columns contain 30 rows while some only 1 or  2). after data retrieves the comboboxes the first combobox (which related to second column) display data correctly but start from 2nd column it shows only one or two rows. all the other values in column not showing. I went through some forums and set my al null values to empty string. but after that comboboxes shows me list of blank entries after last field.

I also tried IS NOT NULL after my query, that also not working :(

how to overcome this situation ? I want to retrieve data to all the comboboxes and without any empty  or null values. I'm using .net framework 2.0

is this possible to programmatically in C# or SQL query, or should I change my database structure ?

(I don't have good knowledge in MySQL. I use workbench for create database :( )

This is my current code

```
 void combobox()
    {

        string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=****************;password=************;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180", dbserverip.Text,curport.Text,currentdb.Text);
        string Query = "select * from estifdb.customconditions ;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader myreader666;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myreader666 = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (myreader666.Read())
            {

                string sName = myreader666.GetString("someval1");
                applicationcombobox.Items.Add(sName);

                string sName2 = myreader666.GetString("someval2");
                applicationcombobox2.Items.Add(sName2);

                string sName3 = myreader666.GetString("someval3");
                applicationcombobox3.Items.Add(sName3);

                string sName4 = myreader666.GetString("someval4");
                applicationcombobox4.Items.Add(sName4);

                string sName5 = myreader666.GetString("someval5");
                applicationcombobox5.Items.Add(sName5);


               // and 50 left
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you also tried something like this:

```
string sName = myreader666.GetString("1003");
if(sName != null && !sName.Equals(""))
    applicationcombobox.Items.Add(sName);
```

Comment: Or even `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sname))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like that:

```
  while (myreader666.Read()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myreader666.FieldCount; ++i) {
      if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
        continue;

      String fieldName = myreader666.GetName(i);
      String fieldValue = myreader666.GetValue(i).ToString();

      //TODO: write a method to find out ComboBox by field name
      ComboBox combo = GetComboByFieldName(fieldName);

      if (combo != null)
        combo.Items.Add(fieldValue);
    }
  }
```

you *have to implement* a method for finding out the right `ComboBox` by its *field name*

Answer (score 0):

Tried using ABS, as in SELECT ABS(column_name) AS AbsoluteA FROM YourTable

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myreader666.GetString("someval1") != null)
{
     string sName = myreader666.GetString("someval1");
     applicationcombobox.Items.Add(sName);
}
```

You can do this. Probably you don't want to add empty.string to the comboBoxes too. In this case add to the `if(myreader666.GetString("someval1") != null && myreader666.GetString("someval1").Trim() != "")`

**Your design is bad you can check the answer with the for loop !**

EDIT:

```
if(myreader666.GetString("someval1") != null)
{
     string sName = myreader666.GetString("someval1");
     applicationcombobox2.Items.Add(sName);
}

if(myreader666.GetString("someval2") != null)
{
     string sName2 = myreader666.GetString("someval2");
     applicationcombobox.Items.Add(sName2);
}
```

and so on for every someval

Comment: thanks for tour answer sir. but after applying your code now only 1st combobx show me the values all rest comboboxes are black :( .is there any other way to do this without while loop ?

Comment: @charith you should write this if for every someval not only for first one. This should be done in diffent if statements.Check the edit

Comment: I did it again. but no luck this time all the comboboxes only shows 2 values :(

Comment: Sir could you please look my code and check it via teamviewer if it's possible ? :( because this is the last part of my application but I cant figure out how can I overcome this